# Dirty buffer pages after issuing CHECKPOINT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, checkpoint

I am currently working on a test system and due to the nature of the queries I want to optimise, I am trying to simulate a "cold" read a well as I can. Part of that is clearing the buffer cache before performing the queries. From everything I can find dirty buffer pages are supposed to be written during a checkpoint. However, even after issuing a CHECKPOINT, there still seem to be 169 dirty pages of my database in the buffer pool (assessed via `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors WHERE database_id=7 AND is_modified=1`).

Is there anything I am misunderstanding about checkpoints or the content of sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors? If not, why do I still have dirty pages after they were supposedly written away?

Comment: Side note, be aware that the storage engine may behave differently until the cache is warmed up, reading full extents instead of single pages. See https://www.dbdelta.com/performance-testing-with-dbcc-dropcleanbuffers/.

Comment: Thank you, the linked article helped me in a different regard.

Answer (score 9):

A manual `CHECKPOINT` *should* write all dirty pages to disk.  It does this for the database that is active for your connection, not for all databases.  Make sure the current database is the name of whatever `database_id=7` is:

```
USE [YourDatabaseName];
GO

CHECKPOINT;
GO

SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors 
WHERE database_id = 7 AND is_modified = 1;
```

See [How do checkpoints work and what gets logged](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-do-checkpoints-work-and-what-gets-logged/):

> All dirty data file pages for the database are written to disk (all pages that have changed in memory since they were read from disk or since the last checkpoint), regardless of the state of the transaction that made the change.

And [Database Checkpoints (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/database-checkpoints-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15):

| Name | Transact-SQL Interface | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Manual | CHECKPOINT [checkpoint_duration] | Issued when you execute a Transact-SQL CHECKPOINT command. The manual checkpoint occurs in the current database for your connection... |

Note that a *bunch* of things can cause dirty pages show up in `sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors` after all explicit (user initiated) write operations have completed.  Some of these could be in response to `SELECT` queries:

- sync or async stats updates from plan compilation
- query store data collection

Or due to background tasks related to specific SQL Server features:

- columnstore tuple mover
- deferred drop (if tables were truncated or dropped, but extents are still being deallocated in the background
- Change Tracking autocleaup
- PVS cleanup (if using Accelerated Database Recovery on SQL Server 2019)

That's not an exhaustive list, but gives you an idea that you might see dirty pages for many reasons beyond just inserts, updates, and deletes.

Comment: I can't say for sure but my database should have been active since it is the only one I am using on that instance. After running your script, there were still 10 dirty pages. After running it again a little later there are 0 now. From the performance side, a few buffered pages aren't too important but I would still like to know **why** it is not writting _all_ dirty pages every time.

Comment: @Florian Interesting!  Is it possible that there are other users or processes connected to this database that are modifying data pages?

Comment: There should not be, as the instance was created solely for me to run tests on. I am currently investigating as new dirty pages have been appearing. If I am not mistaken, that should only be happening if there are INSERTS, UPDATES or DELETES, and nothing should be changing my database. I have found some NT SERVICE accounts that access the sql server instance and I have no clue what they are doing but I can't find any proof of any of them writing to my database specifically.

Comment: @Florian Do you have Query Store turned on for this database? I'm curious if that might be producing dirty pages at regular intervals. I'll give it a test and see.

Comment: @Florian I just confirmed with a local test that `SELECT` queries will produce modified rows in `sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors` when you have Query Store turned on.  That might be what you're seeing.  All the metadata about queries gets stored in the user database (query text, execution count, compilation stats, runtime stats, etc), which means it goes through the normal buffer pool -> flush to disk process like other data pages.

Comment: Also look out for ghost record cleanup, which may be dirtying pages as it cleans up ghost records after the checkpoint.

Comment: @sqL thanks, L!  I guess there are probably a bazillion different reasons pages might be dirtied after explicit write operations have stopped (deferred drop from a truncate, stats updates, in addition to the things already mentioned).  I'll update my answer to indicate that.

Comment: That makes sense. Yes I am using the Query Store. I will probably deactivate it for the weekend and update my post on monday. The database has not been modified by me since it was created from a backup and those services don't seem to be accessing my database. Maybe some of the system objects they access gather stats about my database and SQL Server queries it internally without there being a query I can trace?

Comment: @Florian It could be queries executed by SQL Server Management Studio that are showing up in the Query Store and thus producing dirty pages.  I updated my answer with some examples (thanks to sqL_handLe for the discussion on that here, and on Twitter).

Comment: @Josh Thanks for all the input! Most of the points in your updates don't apply to my setup. I did however deactivate the query store over the weekend and there are 0 dirty pages right now. So that is some indication that those dirty pages that kept appearing were due to the query store. Does it make sense to update my post?

Comment: @Florian I don't think you need to update your post unless you're looking for more information?